# How to share an image on OneDrive, so that it can be viewed in the browser?

Tags: macos, onedrive

I moved a screenshot in the OneDrive folder on my machine (macOS) and right clicked the image file and selected share. I disabled editing for anyone who has the URL and copied the link:

[image: View of the shared file dialog]

I tested this link with an incognito browser window and it won't show the image as image, instead, it shows the image as file icon while it downloads the image, automatically:

[image: Viewing an image file on the OneDrive cloud]

I can't believe OneDrive lacks an online image viewer. Please tell me that I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was contacting the Microsoft support and discovered that this is a bug that happens sometimes to OneDrive. The solution is to retry sharing the image until it works. I really hope this will be fixed, soon.

Until then, never trust a shared image link until you tested it on OneDrive.